# Compute center-of-mass in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am looking for an **efficient** way to compute the center-of-mass of a 2D `numpy` array using native python and `numpy`. (`scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass` does the job, but I can only use numpy)

```py
# sample data
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [0, 4, 4],
              [0, 0, 0]])

center_of_mass(a)
>>> (1., 1.5) # expected output
```

Comment: Please share a sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center of mass is `sum(mi * xi)/m`, `sum(mi * yi)/m` where `mi` are the masses (= elements of the array) and `xi`, `yi` are the coordinates (indices of the array). `m` is the total mass, i.e. `sum(mi)`.

Example for `a = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])`:

`mi*xi` and `mi*yi` we get from multiplying the masses (i.e. the array) with a coordinate grid obtained from [`mgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html):

```
a * np.mgrid[0:a.shape[0], 0:a.shape[1]]
```

which gives

```
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 0,  1,  4],
        [ 0,  4, 10]]])
```

where the upper part is `mi*yi` and the lower part is `mi*xi`, whose sums are

```
(a * np.mgrid[0:a.shape[0], 0:a.shape[1]]).sum(1).sum(1)
```

which gives `array([12, 19])`.

Dividing this by the total sum `a.sum()` we get the final result of `array([0.8, 1.26666667])`.

So putting it all toghether we have:

```
(a * np.mgrid[0:a.shape[0], 0:a.shape[1]]).sum(1).sum(1)/a.sum()
```

---

Scipy does the same but uses an open grid and broadcasting instead of the full (dense) grid and is therefore faster for larger arrays because it doen't need to allocate memory for the indermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

*(scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass does the job, but I can only use numpy)*

Then it sound like time to [read the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/ndimage/measurements.py#L1232). After reading it, for me its looks like it should work with your limitation (*only use numpy*) as it apparently uses solely python built-ins and `numpy`. Replacement `sum` using `numpy.sum` is required.
EDIT: Added note of replacing `sum` according to comment by @Ricoter.

Comment: Thanks I should have done that! (PS. it uses `scipy.sum` which is different from pythons `sum` but can be replaced by `numpy.sum`)

Answer (score 1):

A less expensive solution wrt. memory and computational time using matrix multiplication:

```py
import numpy as np


def center_of_mass(array: np.ndarray):
    total = array.sum()
    # alternatively with np.arange as well
    x_coord = (array.sum(axis=1) @ range(array.shape[0])) / total
    y_coord = (array.sum(axis=0) @ range(array.shape[1])) / total
    return x_coord, y_coord


a = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0],
                [0, 4, 4],
                [0, 0, 0]])

b = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5]])

print(center_of_mass(a)) # (1.0, 1.5)
print(center_of_mass(b)) # (0.8, 1.2666666666666666)
```